# Using a C-Mex Function in an M-File S-Function in Simulink Real-Time

Tags: matlab, simulink, mex

I have created a Level-2 M-File S-Function which internally calls a C MEX function. This works fine in normal simulink, but is it possible to deploy this to a speedgoat real-time PC? I have the source code of the C-MEX function.

If so, what steps are needed?

I have the original C-Source for the mex file (oringally from the Matlab file exchange).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps here to create a C-Mex S-Function. It is not a comprehensive guide, so if you have any doubts refer to the extensive Mathworks documentation regarding Level 2 C-Mex S-Functions.

[Creating a C-Mex S-Function](http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/toolbox/simulink/sfg/sfcn_rtw8.html)

Pay special attention to putting

> #define S_FUNCTION_NAME wrapsfcn

the **same** as the naming of your main c/cpp file.

Then compile the S-Function using the "mex" command in the Matlab command window. You will need a valid compiler installed (VS2015 Express will do, for instance). Next, create a S-Function block in your model. Under S-Function Name, put the name we mentioned earlier, case-sensitive.

Then, you are ready to build and deploy.

Tested in my speedgoat machine @ R2020b.